# Error using Levene test in R after a group by [error: is not a numeric variable]

Tags: r

I´m trying to use levene Test from "car" library in R with the iris dataset.

The code I have is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(car)
iris %>% group_by (Species) %>% leveneTest( Sepal.Length )
```

From there I´m getting the following error:

```
Error in leveneTest.default(., Sepal.Length) : 
  . is not a numeric variable
```

I don´t know how to fix this, since the data types seem to be of the rigth type:

```
> str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is mainly about R syntax, which is not on topic on CrossValidated. That being said, you can either use the formula interface as in

```
leveneTest(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris)
```

or state the data directly as in

```
leveneTest(y = iris$Sepal.Length, group = iris$Species)
```